# How to create custom escape strategy escaping only double quote (for json) in symfony & twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

A customer wants double quotes and only double quotes escaped for a json output.  This means single quotes should not be escaped as per the default twig html escape strategy, for example:

```
"2565": "Fête Médiéval du Royaume d&#039;Osgoode "
```

The 'js' escape strategy does not fit the bill as it escapes all non-alphanumeric characters.  From Symfony/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php

```
    case 'js':
        // escape all non-alphanumeric characters
        // into their \xHH or \uHHHH representations
```

I thought creating a custom escaping strategy would be the best way to go about it (perhaps  it wasn't, but that's not the end question of this post :-) ).  But how to create the custom strategy and more importantly, how to inject it in the twig environment via Symfony?

Answer (score 2):

In a class extending Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller, the twig environment can first be obtained via the container property of the Controller class:

```
    $twig   = $this->container->get('twig');
```

The setEscaper method can then be used to create the strategy with a callable:

```
    $twig->getExtension('core')->setEscaper('json', function($twigEnv, $string, $charset) {
        return addcslashes($string, '"');
    });
```

In your twig template, set the autoescape strategy

```
{% autoescape 'json' %}
... (json template and twig code) ...
{% endautoescape %}
```

I'm assuming there is a way of setting the default autoescape for all twig templates.  However in my case some twig templates returned xml instead of json.

Answer (score 0):

To extend Julien's answer... The way to set the default autoescape for all templates is:

```
$twig->getExtension('escaper')->setDefaultStrategy('json');
```